# How to print a series of integers from a list, in one line, using List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to print the integers from a list in one line,
and I have to do it using only one line of code, using list comprehensions (assuming that the list is already given to us)

### I've tried this:

```
[j for j in [4,10,22,34]]
```

but in this case, the output is a list, but I need it to be only the numbers

### and I've also tried this:

```
[print(j,end=' ') for j in [4,10,22,34]]
```

but it happens to print a list with 'None' values at the end also, like:

```
4 10 22 34 [None, None, None, None]
```

### -----------

the list I want to be printed is:

```
[4,10,22,34]
```

the output must be exactly:

```
4 10 22 34
```

Comment: Point here is to not use list comprehension. One line codes always is not handy.

Comment: Use of list comprehensions for the 'side-effects' is discouraged, in this case the side effect of displaying the values.  `print` (in Py3) is a function that returns `None`.  You have the right print; just use it in a regular for loop.

Comment: There is no good reason to use a list comprehension here. It's likely that you've misunderstood how your assignment is intended to involve list comprehensions, and/or your assignment sucks. We can't tell without more context.

Comment: This one [print(j,end=' ') for j in [4,10,22,34]] should be correct with Python 3.6. What python version are you using?

Comment: @CaoMinhVu, it prints `None`s at the end.

Comment: What have you just learned?  What is the purpose of this assignment?

Comment: @CaoMinhVu I use 3.7

Comment: @hpaulj It was supposed to be helping with the use of list comprehensions somehow :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get what the other users are saying, but instead of printing within the list comprehension, you might want to consider formatting your output first.

```
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in int_list]))
```

In a way this fulfills your requirements as well.

Comment: I would recommend this approach - if instructions up to this point include this string `join` method.  If it's an assignment it should have a purpose, consolidating some thing they just learned.

Comment: As you are actually creating a new list of the strings a nice alternation could be: `print(' '.join(map(str, int_list)))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I considered it before remembering that list comprehension is a requirement, otherwise we can just do `print(*int_list)`.

Comment: Using a generator expression or an iterator like `map` as the argument to `str.join` doesn't save anything over a list comprehension, as the first step in the implementation of `str.join` is to turn the argument into a list if it's not already a list or tuple. That's because the code needs to iterate over the values more than once, so a one-use iterator isn't going to be useful.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to print your list as a single line:

```
print(*(i for i in [4,10,22,34]))
```

Comment: The generator expression is entirely unnecessary there. Just do `print(*[4,10,22,34])` instead.

Comment: @Blckknght I think that's to account for the weird requirement of having to use list comprehension.

Comment: @Blckknght you are right but I wanted to show that print statement can be used to print a generator.

Answer (score 4):

Use `*` and `print` to get your result:-

```
print(*[4,10,22,34])
```

**Output**

```
4 10 22 34
```

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers are faster, more intuitive, and should be preferred, I would like to add something different, because why not!

```
print(str([4, 10, 22, 34]).strip('[]').replace(',',''))
```